# How to delete values from table passed on a condition on another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm facing this problem:

I have a table called `pins` that stores information about pins on a map, including their ID, the ID of the user that inserted them, other information, and the time they were insert in.
I also have a table called `evaluation`  that only stores their ID and the ID of the user that inserted it.

In my postgres function i'm deleting all pins that were inserted in the last 30 minutes with this instruction:
`DELETE FROM pins WHERE pin_hour <= localtime - interval '30 minute';`

How do I do to also delete from `evaluation` all the pins that have the id of the pins that I deleted on the previous instruction, since they only have 2 columns(pinID and userID)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define a cascading foreign key constraint:

```
alter table evaluations add constraint fk_evaluations_pin
    foreign key (pin_id) references pins (pid_id)
    on delete cascade;
```

If you are unable to do that, you can also delete from both tables in the same query using `returning`:

```
with d as (
      delete from pins
          where pin_hour <= localtime - interval '30 minute'
          returning *
     )
delete from evaluations
    where pin_id in (select pin_id from d);
```

Comment: and so if i delete them from the ```pins``` table, it will get deleted from ```evaluations``` table?

Comment: @Enguias . . . That is how a cascading delete foreign key constraint works.